# Get dates when UTC offset change in specific timezone

Tags: php, date, datetime, timezone

Is there a function in PHP to get a date when timezones UTC offset is changing? For example:

```
$date1 = new DateTime('27.03.2016 03:00:00', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw') );
echo $date1->getOffset();
```

It returns **7200**.

And this:

```
$date2 = new DateTime('27.03.2016 01:00:00', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw') );
echo $date2->getOffset();
```

returns **3600**. 
By running this I know UTC offset in specific date, but I don't know the exact date when this UTC is changing.

Of course I could loop trough all days in a year (with minutes precise), and find out the specic time but... PHP know this date and I think there must be a way - simple function to get it!
Can't find anything at: http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `DateTimeZone::getTransitions()`:

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone("Europe/Berlin");
print_r($timezone->getTransitions());
```

will print something like:

```
[101] => Array
    (
        [ts] => 1445734800
        [time] => 2015-10-25T01:00:00+0000
        [offset] => 3600
        [isdst] => 
        [abbr] => CET
    )

[102] => Array
    (
        [ts] => 1459040400
        [time] => 2016-03-27T01:00:00+0000
        [offset] => 7200
        [isdst] => 1
        [abbr] => CEST
    )

[103] => Array
    (
        [ts] => 1477789200
        [time] => 2016-10-30T01:00:00+0000
        [offset] => 3600
        [isdst] => 
        [abbr] => CET
    )

[104] => Array
    (
        [ts] => 1490490000
        [time] => 2017-03-26T01:00:00+0000
        [offset] => 7200
        [isdst] => 1
        [abbr] => CEST
    )
```

You can limit the transitions you want with the start and end date parameters.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I was looking for. I've edited your answer to show in array values for current year.